# HTML: On my website, links work only using Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, wordpress

Using Google Chrome, Safari and Internet Explorer with different computers in different places, certain links of my website don't work.
It seems that only Firefox makes them work.

For example, on this page:

[My website](http://www.forsafe.it/contatti/)

1. The icons of Facebook and Twitter on right-top of the page don't
   work.
2. The text "Vai al sito di Medlavitalia" in the left sidebar doesn't
   work.
3. The link "Forsafe Srl" beside "Facebook" doesn't work.

Link number 2's code:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.medlavitalia.it">Vai al sito di Medlavitalia</a></li>
</ul>
```

Link number 3's code:

```
<div style="float: left; clear: both; margin-bottom: 7px;">
<div style="float: left; margin: 5px 7px 0 0;"><img src="http://www.forsafe.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/facebook_icon.png" alt="facebook" /></div>
<div style="float: left;"><span style="color: #000000;"><strong>Facebook</strong></span>: <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Forsafe-Srl/1500354113570084" target="_blank">Forsafe Srl</a></div>
</div>
&nbsp;
```

I noticed that the only links that don't work are the ones that go outside of my site.
For example, if I edit link number 2's code like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.forsafe.it">Vai al sito di Medlavitalia</a></li>
</ul>
```

It works perfectly, because www.forsafe.it is my site.

More details, in case they'll help:

- I'm using Wordpress.
- I have the plugin WP Super Cache (I tried disabling it but nothing
  changes).
- I didn't try with mobile browsers.

What could cause this issue?
Thank you all!

EDIT: I just remembered that yesterday something strange happened: clicking on link number 2, it brought me to another page of my website, absolutely not connected with that link.

Comment: Just checked. All links are working in Chrome-38 and IE-11.

Comment: Same, working for me on Chrome-38, IE-11

Comment: I tried with: MacbookAir - Chrome and Safari. iMac - Firefox and Safari. Win7 - Explorer, Firefox and Chrome. Win8 - Explorer, Firefox and Chrome. The results are the same: Firefox works, the others don't. How is that even possible? Have you tried quitting the page, re-entering and doing it again? (I'm just guessing, I don't have any ideas)

Comment: Confirm it working with Chrome 38 (MacOS X). I am guessing you have some plugin/extension in your Chrome (that get's synched through your GMail account) which blocks your links (malware?). Did you try to disable all extras or maybe even a clean install of Chrome? Malware would also explain your weird link behaviour with link #2.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. Like I said I tried with different computer and different browsers. It has to be my site's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem isn't solved. I know that I can't ask again in a second topic, and I know that I can't do this too, but I really need to solve this and I don't know how else to reach your attention.

Comment: You should just wait, sometimes you get anwser after a week. But, your question, it all works in all my browsers. It must be something you have installed or some. Try to remove the supercache wordpress thing.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

It was plugin WP SlimStat's fault.
I tried disabling all plugins and I found out it was it.
Fortunately they've just now updated the plugin and fixed the error.